Input Field focus remove when the state is update in the child
I am using React-RND for resizing and dragging functionality. I have an array where I initially add objects, and I pass this array as a state into the tabPanel (DevExtreme). In the tab content, I am using RND elements for resizing and dragging. Multiple elements are shown depending on their type.
In the child component, I update the state of the text box, which updates the text of a specific element.
The issue is:
When I update the state from the child component, the input field loses focus and the text does not update.
I have tried debugging, and the input field works fine without the handleChangeValue function. However, when I add handleChangeValue, the issue arises. I want the value to update instantly, like a normal input change, while also updating my state.
Child component:
const DroppableBox = ({
  tabId,
  onDrop,
  onTabPenalElementPossition,
  updateTabPanelText,
  contents,
  bringToFrontTabpanlEl,
  setTabPanelDataSource,
}: DroppableBoxProps) => {
  const [tabElements, setTabElements] = useState(contents);
  const handleDrop = (props: any, monitor: any) => {
    const offset = monitor.getSourceClientOffset();
    if (offset) {
      onDrop(tabId, offset, props);
    }
  };

  const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: ItemTypes.ELEMENT,
    drop: handleDrop,
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
  });

  const handleStopDragging = (id: string, d: { x: any; y: any }) => {
    const stateEl = [...tabElements];
    const idx = stateEl.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    if (stateEl[idx] !== -1) {
      if (stateEl[idx].x !== d.x || stateEl[idx].y !== d.y) {
        stateEl[idx] = {
          ...stateEl[idx],
          x: d.x,
          y: d.y,
        };
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
    onTabPenalElementPossition(tabId, id, d);
  };
  const handleResizeStop = (id: string, ref: any, position: any) => {
    const stateEl = tabElements;
    const idx = stateEl.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    if (stateEl[idx] !== -1) {
      if (
        stateEl[idx].width !== ref.offsetWidth ||
        stateEl[idx].height !== ref.offsetHeight
      ) {
        stateEl[idx] = {
          ...stateEl[idx],
          x: position.x,
          y: position.y,
          width: ref.offsetWidth,
          height: ref.offsetHeight,
        };
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
    setTabElements([...stateEl]);
  };
// handleChangeValue start
  const handleChangeValue = (id: string, value: string) => {
    setTabPanelDataSource((prevState: any) =>
      prevState.map((item: any) =>
        item.tabId === tabId
          ? {
              ...item,
              contents: item.contents.map((cont: any) =>
                cont.id === id ? { ...cont, text: value } : cont
              ),
            }
          : item
      )
    );
  };
// handleChangeValue end 

  const innerCanvasElement = document.getElementById(`${tabId}-wrapper`);
  const innerWrapperWidth = innerCanvasElement?.offsetWidth || "auto";
  const innerWrapperHeight = innerCanvasElement?.offsetHeight || "auto";
  return (
    <div
      key={`${tabId}-wrapper`}
      ref={drop}
      id={`${tabId}-wrapper`}
      style={{
        border: isOver ? "2px dashed red" : "2px solid transparent",
        height: "100%",
        position: "relative",
        background: tabId === "tab1" ? "#5f9ea061" : "#f0c3ef80",
      }}
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("RUN parent div");
      }}
    >
      {tabElements.map((element: any, index: number) => (
        <div
          key={element.id + index}
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
        >
          <Rnd
            data-id={element.id}
            key={element.id + index}
            className="selectable"
            bounds={`#${tabId}-wrapper`}
            enableResizing={{
              ...resizeDirections,
              left: element.type !== "tabPanel",
              right: element.type !== "tabPanel",
            }}
            size={{
              width:
                element.type === "tabPanel" ? innerWrapperWidth : element.width,
              height:
                element.type === "tabPanel"
                  ? innerWrapperHeight
                  : element.height,
            }}
            style={{
              minWidth: element?.text?.length || 10,
              zIndex: element.isActive ? 99 : 0,
              border: contents.find((item) => item.id === element.id)?.isActive
                ? "1px solid blue"
                : "",
            }}
            position={{
              x: element.type === "tabPanel" ? 0 : element.x,
              y: element.type === "tabPanel" ? 0 : element.y,
            }}
            onDragStop={(e, d) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              handleStopDragging(element.id, d);
            }}
            onResizeStop={(_e, _direction, ref, _delta, position) => {
              handleResizeStop(element.id, ref, position);
            }}
            onMouseDown={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              if (element.type !== "tabPanel") {
                bringToFrontTabpanlEl(tabId, element.id);
              }
            }}
          >
            {element.type === "textbox" && (
              <input
                value={element.text}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  e.stopPropagation();
                  handleChangeValue(element.id, e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            )}
          </Rnd>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DroppableBox;

Parent component:
<div
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    bringToFront(element.id);
  }}
  style={{ height: "100%" }}
>
  <TabPanel
    tabsPosition={element.tabsPosition || "left"}
    stylingMode={element?.tabsStyleMode}
    iconPosition={element?.tabsIconPositon}
    // onContentReady={() => {
    //   if (element.type === "tabPanel") {
    //     console.log("onContentReady ---");
    //     // bringToFront(element.id);
    //   }
    // }}
    width="100%"
    height={"100%"}
    // onInitialized={(e: any) => {
    //   e.element.lastChild.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    // }}
    // onTitleClick={(e: any) => {
    //   if (e.itemIndex === 0) {
    //     e.element.lastChild.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    //   }
    // }}
    elementAttr={{
      style:
        "border:5px solid red !important; height:100%; padding:0",
    }}
    dataSource={tabPanelDataSource}
    itemComponent={({ data }: any) => (
      <DroppableBox
        {...data}
        bringToFrontTabpanlEl={bringToFrontTabpanlEl}
        onDrop={handleDrop}
        onTabPenalElementPossition={onTabPenalElementPossition}
        onTabPanelResizeStop={onTabPanelResizeStop}
        updateTabPanelText={updateTabPanelText}
        setTabPanelDataSource={setTabPanelDataSource}
      />
    )}
  />
</div>

